# ConEmu's startup option

Tags: conemu, autostart

Where I can find autostart ConEmu option? I have searched everywhere (google it too) and can't find it.

Comment: Is it related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/13374719/3363219

Comment: The above link is for how to get ConEmu to run a bat file when it starts up or opens a new tab. The below answer is the way to get windows to launch ConEmu when it starts up.

Answer (score 26):

Looks like there is no built-in option for ConEmu autostart. But there is an easy workaround - add it to autostart manually:

1. `Win+R` -> open Run menu
2. Type `shell:startup`, press Enter
3. Create shortcut to ConEmu in opened folder

Answer (score 9):

Piggybacking off The Godfather's solution which is correct, I would also add a -min to the  [end of the shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMHpn.png) path you make or else ConEmu pops up randomly on startup interrupting you.